# Simple example of signalR not working

Tags: signalr

Not able to get SignalR working in my machine (with IE9). On entering some text and clicking submit, the text is not getting listed as intended. Also, I would expect the list getting updated from multiple instances of browser and It does not happen. There is no error. Could anybody help here?

### C#

```
namespace TestSignalR.Hubs
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Web;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for ChatHub.
    /// </summary>
    public class ChatHub : SignalR.Hubs.Hub
    {
        public void TestMessage(string message)
        {
            Clients.writeMessage(message);
        }
    }
}
```

### ASPX

```
<input type="text" name="txtInput" id="txtInput" />
<button id="btnSubmit">Submit</button>

<ul id="messages">
</ul>
<script type="text/javascript" src="SignalR/Hubs"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (message) {
        var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

        chat.writeMessage = function (message) {
            $("#messages").append("<li>" + message + "</li>");
        };

        $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
            var text = $("#txtInput").val();
            chat.testMessage(text);
        });

        $.connection.hub.start();
    });

</script>
```

Master page has the references for the JQuery and SignalR files:-

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/jquery.signalR-0.5.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: nothing wrong with the code, works on my machine. Only difference jquery 1.7.2. Have you checked if all js scripts are found in IE9?

Comment: that "jquery-1.6.4.min.js" came with Nuget SignalR.

Comment: @Wim, What do you mean by "if all js scripts are found in IE9"?

Comment: in IE9 developer tools scripts, can you see all javascript files?

Answer (score 3):

Today I was working with the same issue.

First you need to add an atribute to your Hub with the name, as following:

```
[HubName("chathub")]
public class ChatHub : SignalR.Hubs.Hub
```

The next to do is to change the order of your calls in the javascript. You need to do the connection next to instantiate the hub.
So, the code will be as following:

```
$(document).ready(function (message) {
   var chat = $.connection.chatHub;

   $.connection.hub.start();

   chat.writeMessage = function (message) {
      $("#messages").append("<li>" + message + "</li>");
   };

    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        var text = $("#txtInput").val();
        chat.testMessage(text);
    });        
 });
```

I hope it works for you.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `chat.client.writeMessage` and `chat.server.testMessage`

Answer (score 0):

Please install the 1.0 version of SignalR from Nuget as well. From your script references it looks like you are using 0.5.2 and the latest supported version at the time of writing this post is 1.0. Please download Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR from Nuget